# Why these Python send / receive socket functions work if invoked slowly, but fail if invoked quickly in a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have a client and a server, where the server needs to send a number of text files to the client.

The send file function receives the socket and the path of the file to send:

```
CHUNKSIZE = 1_000_000
def send_file(sock, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        sock.sendall(f'{os.path.getsize(filepath)}'.encode() + b'\r\n')

        # Send the file in chunks so large files can be handled.
        while True:
            data = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            sock.send(data)
```

And the receive file function receives the client socket and the path where to save the incoming file:

```
CHUNKSIZE = 1_000_000
def receive_file(sock, filepath):
    with sock.makefile('rb') as file_socket:
        length = int(file_socket.readline())

        # Read the data in chunks so it can handle large files.
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            while length:
                chunk = min(length, CHUNKSIZE)
                data = file_socket.read(chunk)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)
                length -= len(data)

    if length != 0:
        print('Invalid download.')
    else:
        print('Done.')
```

It works by sending the file size as the first line, then sending the text file line by line.

Both are invoked in loops in the client and the server, so that files are sent and saved one by one.

It works fine if I put a breakpoint and invoke these functions slowly. But If I let the program run uninterrupted, it fails when reading the size of the second file:

```
  File "/home/stark/Work/test/networking.py", line 29, in receive_file
    length = int(file_socket.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'00,1851,-34,-58,782,-11.91,13.87,-99.55,1730,-16,-32,545,-12.12,19.70,-99.55,1564,-8,-10,177,-12.53,24.90,-99.55,1564,-8,-5,88,-12.53,25.99,-99.55,1564,-8,-3,43,-12.53,26.54,-99.55,0,60,0\r\n'
```

Clearly a lot more data is being received by that `length = int(file_socket.readline())` line.

My questions: why is that? Shouldn't that line read only the size given that it's always sent with a trailing `\n`?

How can I fix this so that multiple files can be sent in a row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're reusing the same connection and what happens is your `file_socket` being buffered means... you've actually `recv`ed more from your socket then you'd think with your read loop.

I.e. the receiver consumes more data from your socket and next time you attempt to `readline()` you end up reading rest of the previous file up to the new line contained therein or of the next length information.

This also means your initial problem actually is you've skipped a while. Effect of which is next read line is not an `int` you expected and hence the observed failure.

You can say:

```
with sock.makefile('rb', buffering=0) as file_socket:
```

instead to force the file like access being unbuffered. Or actually handle the receiving and buffering and parsing of incoming bytes (understanding where one file ends and the next one begins) on your own (instead of file like wrapper and `readline`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that socket communication is based on TCP/IP, does not matter if it's same machine (you use loopback in such cases) or different machines. So, you've got some IP addresses between which the connection is established. Going further, it involves accessing your network adapter, ie takes relatively long in comparison to accessing eg. RAM. Additionally, the adapter itself manages when to send particular data frames (lower ISO/OSI layers). Basically, in case of TCP there's ACK required, but on standard PC this is usually not some **industrial**, real-time ethernet.

So, in your code, you've got a `while True` loop without any sleep and you don't check what does `sock.send` returns. Even if something goes wrong with particular data frame, you ignore it and try to send next. **On first glance it appears that something has been cached and receiver received what was flushed once connection was re-established.**

So, first thing which you should do is check if `sock.send` indeed returned number of bytes sent. If not, I believe the frame should be re-sent. Another thing which I strongly recommend in such cases is think of some custom protocol (this is usually called **application layer** in context of OSI/ISO stack). For example, you might have 4 types of frames: START, FILESIZE, DATA, END, assign unique ID and start each frame with the identifier. Then, START is gonna be empty, FILESIZE gonna contain single uint16, DATA is gonna contain {FILE NUMBER, LINE NUMBER, LINE_LENGTH, LINE} and END is gonna be empty. Then, once you've got entire frame on the client, you can safely assemble the information you received.

Comment: Thanks! This was also useful. I am surprised python doesn't have some utility methods for common types of messages. Perhaps there is a library I haven't found yet.